# Mongodb Schema considering sub-document to avoid multiple reads

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, database-schema, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am trying to come up with a MongoDB document model and would like others opinions. I want to have a Document that represents an Employee. This table will contain all attributes of an employee (I.e. firstName, LastName).  Now where I am stuck coming from the relational realm, is the need to store a list of employees an employee can access.  In other words lets say Employee A is a Manager. I need to store the direct reports that he manages, in order to use this in various applications.  In relational I would have a mapping table that tied an employee to many employees.  In mongo not being able join documents, do you think I should utilize an embeded (sub-document) to store the list of accessible employees as part of the Employee document?  Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your using employee groups (Accounting, HR, etc) You'll probably be fine adding the employee name, mongo Object ID, and any other information unique to that manager / employee relationship as a sub document to the managers document.

With that in place you could probably do your reporting on these relationships through a simple aggregation.

This is all IMHO, and begs the question; Is simple aggregation another oxymoron like military intelligence?

Comment: Thanks. There is a more complex system handeling security and groups.  By the time it gits to this system we are given just a list of employees that employee can view.

Comment: Military intelligence is not really an oxymoron.